# Difference between "va faire" and "ira faire"

Tags: futur, temps-composés, futur-proche

Is there any difference between "va faire" and "ira faire" ? Example:

- Il va faire du cerf-volant demain.
- Il ira faire du cerf-volant demain.

Comment: The sample sentences in the answer written by @Eauquidort both make sense to me. However, I can't imagine a situation in which your second sentence, *Il ira faire du cerf-volant demain* would make sense. I agree with Eau qui dort that there is a difference between the two expressions, with one involving movement and the other not, but in the case of *faire du cerf-volant* there is implicit movement anyway, as this isn't something you would do in your back yard! In other words, the movement is already included in the action.  So, there would never be a need for "ira" in this particular example.

Comment: Even if "ira" is not required in my sentence because the movement is already implicit, I assume it still can be used for emphasis ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by emphasis.  Maybe you mean that it is emphasizing the *going* -- the fact that the boy will be *going elsewhere* for the activity.  If so, then yes. // Your choice of verbs for talking about the future is actually quite simple.  You can either use "va" with the verb in question (equivalent to *he's going to take his make-up test tomorrow*) or you can conjugate the verb in question in the future tense (equivalent to *he will take the make-up test tomorrow*).  The third option you came up with, where you try to do both things (a form of *aller* plus a ...

Comment: ... conjugation in the future tense) is a bit weird.  Now, if you want to ask about the difference between the two valid options, that would be a separate question.  If it hasn't been asked yet (sorry, I have not looked to see if it has), that would be an interesting question, I think.

Comment: Yes, I meant emphasis on the movement. Thanks! I am well aware of the future forms of French, the point here was understanding the nuance of using "ira faire qqch" and it is now clear.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"Ira" necessitates that some movement will happen (in other words, it's a verb of movement in the future tense), while "va" doesn't.

Take a sentence like "Elle ira travailler chez elle demain". It only makes sense if she's not currently at home. The same sentence with "va" wouldn't have the same truth conditionals, it's fine to use whether she's already home or not. In order to have an equivalent sentence using "va", youd need to use "Elle va aller travailler chez elle demain"

Comment: How could I translate the 2nd sentence to English to express the same meaning?

Comment: He will go and play *flying-deer* ;-)

Comment: @AlanEvangelista - She's going to her [other?] house tomorrow to do some work.  (That's not a literal word-for-word translation -- it's a *functional* translation that conveys the same meaning as the given sentence.)  Keep in mind that a simple future would be *Elle travaillera chez elle demain*.  So,  "Elle va *aller* travailler" has to be different from "She will work."

Comment: Oh, I just realized you were maybe requesting a translation of the second sentence in the original post.  Sorry.  If that is the case: the second sentence in your original post would not be authentic, so no point in translating it.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista In English it's similar to the phrasal verb "going off to" or "going out to". "She's going to work tomorrow" vs "she's going off to work tomorrow." The first is pure grammar and the second indicates physical motion.

Comment: @jiliagre play flying deer?

Comment: Looks like my play of words was missed. Anyway, my translation of the second sentence would be something like: "He will go and fly a kite tomorrow" vs "He will fly a kite tomorrow".

Comment: @Alan: In English the distinction would be similar to “he's going to fly a kite” vs “he will go fly a kite” (literally of course). “Going off/out to” is closer to “partir/sortir faire du cerf-volant”.

Comment: @Stéphane Gimenez, 1) to go off to do sth. = to leave a place and go somewhere else to do sth. Isn't that the exact meaning of "ira faire qqch"? 2) "to go do sth" seems a very good translation but, just to be sure, that is only used in parts of US, right?

Comment: 1. Nope, the emphasis on having a break or leaving a place is not present in “ira faire quelque chose”. 2. Yep, possibly, but the more important difference between the two sentences you gave in the question is the tense/aspect change.

Answer (score -3):

There is no great difference since the respective tenses are two future tenses, the "futur immédiat" and the "future simple", but that is true only as far as the action per se is concerned.

There can be a subtle difference; in the first case you are dealing with a matter of fact statement. In the second you can stress « demain » and then you are saying that he is not going to do it now or at another time, you are saying that some other time than tomorrow that has been considered will not do.

Here is another subtle difference; the "future simple" can be used for a sarcastic effect. The pronunciation, of course, is crucial in the conveying of the sarcasm and I will not go into that as the discussion is beyond my means, but let it be said that the "futur immédiat" is not proper for this purpose. The sarcasm is to the effect that such a thing is a trivial occupation in comparison to something else that is in question.

- — Pourquoi ne pas le laisser lire ses Mickey Mouse et ses Donald Duck ?
  — Quand son instituteur l'interrogera sur ses leçon il lui récitera Mickey Mouse !
  *"il va lui réciter" is not proper, but it must be said again, the intonation is very important*

As the first form is used for  matter of fact statements it is used much more than the second ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=il+ira+faire%2Cil+va+faire&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cil%20ira%20faire%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cil%20va%20faire%3B%2Cc0)).

An important difference lies in what prompted someone answering with either one of those forms : if the reply is meant to tell someone that the boy/man will not be able to do something else in reason of his playing with a kite, you must use the form in the "futur immédiat"; the other one does not convey the message idiomatically.

Comment: I think that any tense can express sarcasm. Could you give more details of how the sentence with the Futur Simple may be used sarcastically (and why the sentence with the Futur Proche cannot achieve the same effect) ?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista True, sarcasm can be embodied in any form, provided, among other things, that you have at your command the proper intonations; however, the case I mention  is a tipyfied instance of that, it's dedicated to that particular type of sarcasm I mention and not  any sort you might have in mind. There are other points, besides the highlighting of  triviality; it can be derisiveness, unreasonableness, etc. (triviality being merely typical).

Comment: @AlanEvangelista I'll add a little example that might be instructive.

Comment: This andwer is missing the real difference between the sentences and the "sarcastic" part is nonsensical.

Comment: Plainly wrong, the answer should be deleted.

Comment: @petitrien Plainly right, this answer is going to remain where it's at !

Comment: @LPH. None so deaf…

Comment: Can you provide a reference for the sarcastic aspect of your answer? I have not found this anywhere.

Comment: @Dimitris I do have an example that is not of my invention and there are quantities of such examples; it is clear that in this usage you can't substitute « vous allez aller » for « vous irez » as then the effect is lost. https://books.google.fr/books?id=iGgsyVtv6u8C&q=%22vous+irez%22&dq=%22vous+irez%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwicuLfip43kAhXOGewKHQ42AhgQ6AEIRjAF I have no confirmation by a linguistic authority, nevertheless, anyone will tell you that the words « vous irez » are not a statement of fact but are the indication of a sarcastic view of the action that is introduced by it.

Comment: Thank your very much for your quick feedback. Nevertheless, two native speakers (petitrien et jlliagre) seems not to agree with this aspect. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Dimitris What can I say more? They say "no", I say "yes", that's all there is about it. I have no more evidence, but take note of that example I provided and let some of your acquaintances have a look at it, ask them what they think.